# Select outer edges only

Tags: modeling, mesh, selection-tools

Is there a way to select only outer edges of mesh. I can select them with holding shift and edge click but I dont want to do it manualy since there is lots of it. Mesh looks like this:
[image]

Comment: There is actually a way of selecting outer edges only which I just figured out. Since this mesh has "stacked" UV I was able to select outer vertices only. But I still dont know if this is only good way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

Blender can automatically detect the the boundary.

1. Select all edges *(Select > All)*
2. *Select > Select Loops > Boundary Loop*
3. Done.

[image]